# iOS core data group by

Tags: ios, core-data, group-by, xmppframework

in core data, I have two entities. XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject & XMPPGroupCoreDataStorageObject.

XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject has a property which holds an array of XMPPGroupCoreDataStorageObject (@property (nonatomic, strong) NSSet * groups;)

XMPPGroupCoreDataStorageObject also has a property which hold an array of XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject  (@property (nonatomic, strong) NSSet* users;)

I want to query the XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject which is group by XMPPGroupCoreDataStorageObject. This is many-to-many mapping.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot group by a many-to-many relationship because the child entity (`User` in your case) would occur more than once.

Instead, fetch by what you want to group by (`Group` in your case). For displaying these in e.g. a table view, use the fetched groups to populate the table view section headers, and display the associated `User`s in the table view rows.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, if you are able to modify the data model, is to implement an intermediate entity to model the many-many relationship.  So rather than:

```
User <<<--->>> Group
```

you would have

```
User <--->>> GroupMember <<<---> Group
```

You can then base your fetch on the `GroupMember` entity.  Since this has to-one relationships to both `User` and `Group`, you could use a `NSFetchedResultsController` to do the grouping, with `sectionNameKeyPath` set to "group.groupName" (or whatever attribute), and then populate the table view based on attributes of the `user` relationship (e.g. `user.userName`).  But the downside is that creating and deleting the relationship involves a bit more work inserting/deleting the `GroupMember` objects.

Comment: I agree that it makes the NSFetchedResultsController more usable in a standard way. However, if the "join table" does not include additional data, it is usually preferable to go with a standard many-to-many relationship.

Comment: @Mundi Agreed.  But I thought it worth including this option, for those for whom NSFetchedResultsController is important.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this alternative. Of course, a standard many-to-many relationship is perfectly fine with a NSFetchedResultsController.

Comment: @Mundi But how would the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method work in such a case? You would retrieve the Group and then have to make a fetch for Users within that group in order to get them correctly sorted. Isn't this very inefficient?

Comment: @pbasdf Using your solution, how do you implement cellForRowAtIndexPath:?

Comment: No, one can just sort with descriptor on the fly. Works very well. Something like `group.users.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([NSSortDescriptor(key:"name" ascending:true)])[indexPath.row]`

Comment: @cfisher The `cellForRowAtIndexPath` would be very similar to usual: sort the FRC by `group.groupName` and `user.userName` (or whatever).  Then use something like `GroupMember *member = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];` and then `User *user = member.user` will give you a reference to the User for that row, so you can use whatever User attributes to configure the cell.  I should mention another downside: the FRC delegate methods will not be fired for changes to either the User objects or Group objects (the FRC only observes the fetched objects: ie. GroupMembers.)